# find server mail address

Tags: exchange-2003, mx-record

A friend has asked if I can help him out on a project he's doing, however it looks like I'm struggling! Hoping I'm posting in the right place, many apologies if it's wrong. Been searching all day to what seems an easy question:

Company he's organising a website for runs their mail through a self-run server running Microsoft Mail Exchange 2003. He was tasked for setting up their new website+URL. However when moving assets to the new server, they have "lost" the MX records of the self-run mail server, and currently the records are pointing to the default MX records of the new host (Dreamhost) which he's made new emails for as a stop-gap measure.

So it appears as though everything is set up and will operate as it has been, however I'm unsure how to get the self-run server information to input in to the new websites MX records?

Researching this morning it seems as though it can be done by going in to the self-run server, running an nslookup check and using "set q=mx" to target mx records?

How do I get the name of this server so I can punch it in the the MX records? Any help would be much appreciated, I'll do my best to provide more information, however I'm a 4th party in all this.

I've a background in web design and development, currently doing 1st year computer science (if that gives you an idea of my knowledge base!)

How do I go from getting an IP address of this self-run server, and change it in to something like mail.website.com that can be used to input in to the mx records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the IP of the server (talk with the hosting provider, etc.)
2. Create a DNS `A` record pointing mail.example.com to the IP you got in step #1.
3. Create your MX record.

To directly address your point about being able to get the MX record by issuing a DNS query from the server itself, that is not a reliable method to get this information.

Comment: Awesome! Perfect. Sorry, this is the kind of task that should be handled by someone with background in it. Thanks for helping out here! :)